# Where can I find Industry Standard Stock Prices?

Tags: stock-markets, stock-analysis, stock-valuation

I'm taking up Business Finance and part of my research project is to compare my assigned company's yearly stock prices to the industry standard. However, I do not know where to find this nor am I using the right keywords on Google search engine.

Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 1):

> My research project is to compare my assigned company's yearly stock
> prices to the industry standard.

If you are looking for a broad index for US stocks you could use the Standard and Poor's 500 also known as the S&P 500. This should be easy to find.  You could also use one of the Russel indexes.

The thing you are looking for is called an Index. There are indexes for a particular country. There are indexes for a particular industry: mining, Health care, Financial sector, Real Estate...

You will have to decide which is the most appropriate for your project.